# Finding Negative Cycles in Graph

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, bellman-ford

I tried the following code, to find negative cycle. While running the code faced error : "NameError: name 'NetworkXUnbounded' is not defined"

I am trying to run bellman-ford algorithm here. Algo raises an Exception of type "NetworkXUnbounded", which I tried to handle with exception handling shown below.

```py
import pandas as pd 
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("fx_rate_3.csv") 
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,source='A', target='B', edge_attr ['weight'], create_using=nx.DiGraph())

def find_path(digraph, start):
    try:
        path = nx.bellman_ford_predecessor_and_distance(digraph, start, 'weight') 
        return path
    except NetworkXUnbounded:
        cycles = nx.simple_cycles(digraph)
        for cycle in cycles:
            print (cycle)
```

Comment: I am trying to find negative cycle (Not Detect) in graph. Once Negative cycle is found, I want to get the edge list (or Nodes) it followed. 
I tried the above code but was unsuccessful work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `NetworkXUnbounded` from the `networkX` module first before using it. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
from networkx import NetworkXUnbounded  # <---- Import the exception before using it

df = pd.read_csv("fx_rate_3.csv") 
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,source='A', target='B', edge_attr ['weight'], create_using=nx.DiGraph())

def find_path(digraph, start):
    try:
        path = nx.bellman_ford_predecessor_and_distance(digraph, start, 'weight') 
        return path
    except NetworkXUnbounded:
        cycles = nx.simple_cycles(digraph)
        for cycle in cycles:
            print (cycle)
```

Also beware that this exception might occur even if negative weight edge exists in an undirected Graph:

> If the (di)graph contains a negative cost (di)cycle, the algorithm raises an exception to indicate the presence of the negative cost (di)cycle. Note: any negative weight edge in an undirected graph is a negative cost cycle.

See [the documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.bellman_ford_predecessor_and_distance.html) for more info.